# Web table search and click

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have a problem for searchung table values in web table .

I have a excel table contain two coloumns .

Name |   Branch ,

Roger |   london

I have web table in IE contains  contain multiple rows . And few coloums

Name |  branch ,

Roger  | london

I need to take two of my excel values and serach kn web table and then click on name .

I need to match .

Problem is there are multiple same name with diffirent branches . But i need to click only on the roger which match with london .

I am using object cloning for this process . I can able search and click ln name . But i need to match with brach and click ..

If anybody have idea of having x path . Then please let me know how to use in automation anywhere to match with two values

Thanks

Comment: This actually depends on the website that you're automating. Try capturing one name and comment here the XPath.

Comment: Domx path for table 

//form[ @name='orderform' ]/table[1]

Domx path for name and branch
//form[ @name='orderform' ]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/span[1]

//form[ @name='orderform' ]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[3]/span[1]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use If for Object Properties and look for Name cell.
2. IF above satisfied, then check another If for Object Properties and Look for City
3. If Both True, then use object cloning with rpoperties of Name in first If.

Use If Object Property correctly, purpose will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

So Internet explorer tables are the most challenging stuff in Web UI automation.

Object clone the table , in options you will get something as find item by text, this would return row column value .
Do this for both text once the row values for both of them is same that means they are in same row , you can click item by index\RowColumn values.

Second way is if you see the domXpath Domx path for table //form[ @name='orderform' ]/table[1] Domx path for name and branch //form[ @name='orderform' ]/table[1]/tbody[1]/**tr[3]/td[1]**/span[1] //form[ @name='orderform' ]/table[1]/tbody[1]/**tr[3]/td[3**]/span[1

The bold values are row column values , you need to check loop in such a way that you go through entire table contents this you can do by replacing these numbers with $counter$ or similar variable used in your loop , find a row column where values match your criteria and click those exact position . For clicking pickup row Column values variablize them , place them in an object cloning command and select click from drop down options.

Instead you can save internet table in a csv and apply the same logic of finding row n column numbers , then use those numbers in online table and click using object cloning.